# My aws cli command returns an error message "The specified key does not exist."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

here is the command I used, and it works fine when there is no space space in S3 URL
`aws s3 ls <s3://bucket/folder/> --recursive | awk '{print $4}' | awk "NR >= 2" | xargs -I %%% aws s3api restore -object --bucket <bucket> --restore-request Days=3,GlacierJobParameters={"Tier"="Bulk"} --key %%%`
But if there is space in s3 url like the picture I attached, it returns an error message. I don't know what the problem is, how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html - *Characters that might require special handling* include the space. Having a space in the name is a bad idea as you just discovered, try e.g. wrapping it in `"` or url encoding it or ...

Comment: You _could_ use something like `aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket> --query "Contents[].Key" | jq ".[]" | sed 's/"\(.*\)"/aws s3api restore -object --bucket <bucket> --restore-request Days=3,GlacierJobParameters={"Tier"="Bulk"} --key $'"'"'\1'"'"'/' | bash` to get raw strings, but you're _much_ better off writting a script to do this.